# Exposing EF6 model subsets via WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

For example, I have a EF6 model like this:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProfileProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set }
    public int Name { get; set }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set }
    public long Size { get; set }

    public string ContentPath { get; set }
}
```

And now I want to create a WebAPI that allows to:

- Create a new user
- Update user's name
- Modify the list of user's books

However, here are a few tricks to it which don't let me use tutorials right off:

- Some fields are either irrelevant or confidential and must not be exposed via WebAPI, for example: `User.Id`, `User.Properties`, and nested `User.Books[x].ContentPath`.
- Only a small subset of fields is editable (in the example, `User.Name`).
- Only a small subset of operations (CRUD) is available, therefore it's not a REST service.

The first thing that comes to mind is create extra classes for each exposed model. However, maintaining them and writing code that converts data from database models to those WebAPI-friendly classes and back is too bothersome. Is there a more simple and automated way?

The ideal approach would be one which requires writing as little redundant code as possible. Maybe there is a set of attributes to mark fields with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in thinking you should create more classes. For each exposed action (change name,  create user, etc...) you should create a ViewModel that exposes only the fields you need.

```
public class ChangeUserNameViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string NewName { get; set; }
}
```

It's easy to convert your view model to your domain model and back again using something like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. AutoMapper looks really nice. Isn't it slow though, judging by the assumption that it uses Reflection?

Comment: I've never had any speed issues with it. If your concerned you could use some plain factories to do the conversion.